# order by rows that exist in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables that are not connected by a foreign key.

One called `message_log` and another called `assigned_conversation`.

`assigned_conversation` also contains the `match_id` column

I have the query below that works with no issues.

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM   message_log m 
WHERE  m.from_id <> 'MYID' 
       AND m.to_id = 'MYID' 
       AND m.unix_timestamp = (SELECT Max(unix_timestamp) 
                               FROM   message_log 
                               WHERE  match_id = m.match_id 
                               GROUP  BY match_id)
```

The only thing I want to change for the query above is how the results is sorted.

Is it possible to have the results sorted in a way that for `match_id`s that exists in the `assigned_conversation` table to be placed on the top of the results and for `match_id`s that don't exist in the `assigned_conversation` table to be sorted after the ones that do exist in the `assigned_conversation` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to order using a `CASE` expression which checks if a given `match_id` in the outer query can be found in the `assigned_conversation` table.

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM   message_log m
WHERE  m.from_id <> 'MYID' 
   AND m.to_id = 'MYID' 
   AND m.unix_timestamp = (SELECT Max(unix_timestamp) 
                           FROM   message_log 
                           WHERE  match_id = m.match_id 
                           GROUP  BY match_id)
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM assigned_conversation a
                      WHERE a.match_id = m.match_id)
         THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
```

Note that we could have tried left joining to `assigned_conversation`, but that might have introduced duplicates into your result set, assuming a `match_id` in the outer query could appear more than once in `assigned_conversation`.  Using `EXISTS` gets around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the sub query you can just use distinct to make sure you get only the newest log entry and then by left joining assigned_conversation and ordering by first match_id is null and then m.unix_timestamp desc you should get the expected result in a clean and efficient way

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.* 
FROM   message_log m 
left join assigned_conversation ac on ac.match_id = m.match_id
WHERE  m.from_id <> 'MYID' 
       AND m.to_id = 'MYID' 
ORDER BY ac.match_id is null, m.unix_timestamp desc
```

Comment: Left joining may introduce duplicates into the result set, especiallly if `match_id` be a foreign key in the `assigned_conversation` table.

Comment: using DISTINCT prevents that as long as no column from "assigned_conversation" is used in the select, in that case you could use DISTINCT ON (m)

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify the query to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ml.match_id) ml.* 
FROM message_log ml 
WHERE ml.from_id <> 'MYID' AND
      ml.to_id = 'MYID' 
ORDER BY ml.match_id, ml.unix_timestamp DESC;
```

You can then use this as a subquery to get the final ordering you want:

```
SELECT ml.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (ml.match_id) ml.*
      FROM message_log ml 
      WHERE ml.from_id <> 'MYID' AND
            ml.to_id = 'MYID' 
      ORDER BY ml.match_id, ml.unix_timestamp DESC
     ) ml
ORDER BY (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM assigned_conversation ac WHERE ac.match_id = ml.match_id))::int DESC,
         match_id;
```

However, I would be inclined to add the flag to the data in the result set:

```
SELECT ml.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (ml.match_id) ml.*,
             (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM assigned_conversation ac WHERE ac.match_id = ml.match_id))::int as ac_flag
      FROM message_log ml 
      WHERE ml.from_id <> 'MYID' AND
            ml.to_id = 'MYID' 
      ORDER BY ml.match_id, ml.unix_timestamp DESC
     ) ml
ORDER BY ac_flag desc, match_id;
```